# error when connecting solr to mysql

Tags: java, mysql, apache, tomcat, solr

I was able to install Tomcat and solr, and I can view the solr dashboard at SERVERIP:8080/solr

Next, I am trying to access MySQL via solr so that I can start indexing some data.  I added the following lines to my solrconfig.xml file just under the `<config>` tag:

`<requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="config">data-config.xml</str>
    </lst>
    </requestHandler>`

My data-config.xml file looks like this:

`<dataConfig>
    <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource"
     driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
     url="jdbc:mysql://`localhost`/my_database"
     user="my_username"
     password="my_password"
     />
     <document>
     <entity name="user"
     query="select id, first_name, last_name from user;">
     <field column="id" name="id"/>
     <field column="first_name" name="first_name"/>
     <field column="last_name" name="last_name"/>
     </entity>
     </document>
    </dataConfig>`

However, when I restart Tomcat, I get a long error message.  Here are the first few lines:

`HTTP Status 500 - {msg=SolrCore 'collection1' is not available due to init failure: RequestHandler init failure,trace=org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: SolrCore 'collection1' is not available due to init failure: RequestHandler init failure at  org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.getCore(CoreContainer.java:827) at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:317) at ...`

Does anyone know where I would even start to debug this error?

Some other threads suggest that this may be a file permission error, but I have double-checked that the solr directory is writeable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took a while, but I was able to resolve the error message.

First, I had to edit the existing schema.xml file in the tomcat/solr/collection1/conf directory.

Second, I had to create a lib directory in the tomcat/solr directory, and then copy all files from the original dist directory (/opt/solr/dist) to the tomcat/solr/lib directory.  The important files to copy were solr-dataimporthandler-4.7.1.jar, solr-dataimporthandler-extras-4.7.1.jar and I also needed to download mysql-connector-java-5.1.30-bin.jar

Hopefully this helps someone out there!

PS: I'm still unable to connect to MySQL, but solr is running without any fatal error messages and tries to index something.  I probably just need to tweak the configuration files a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add **mysql jar** to the lib directory in your solr home folder. Once you do that it will work.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I actually did this already, so this is not the solution for my scenario, but this may help others.

Comment: You have to edit schema file with your used attributes i.e firstname and lastname

Comment: I tried adding fields to schema.xml following online tutorials.  Unfortunately, after restarting Tomcat, I still get the same error in solr.  Darn it.